# Blazor NavigationManager works but Redirects backs To same Page Immediately

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, blazor-server-side

This is my Index.razor Page.

```
@page "/"
@inject NavigationManager navigation
<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

    <div class="login-page">
      <div class="form">
        <div class="login">
          <div class="login-header">
            <h3>LOGIN</h3>
            <p>Please enter your credentials to login.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <form class="login-form">
          <input type="text" placeholder="username"/>
          <input type="password" placeholder="password"/>
          <button @onclick=ValidateCredentials>login</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>

@code{
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        
    }
    public void ValidateCredentials(EventArgs e)
    {
        navigation.NavigateTo("/fetchdata");
    }
}
```

When I click on Login button over the UI the fetchdata pages pops but immediately the index.razor pages comes back
eg Onclick from Index.razor ->fetchdata.razor(it appears for millisecond)-->index.razor login uI starts showing.

Please guide me what am I doing wrong.I am very new to Blazor but i guess this
(It could onclick event call from html form I might to use Editcontext model )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Explanation: Since you embed a button Html element within a form element, the type attribute of the button element defaults to "submit", which is why the first action performed is the submission of the form to nowhere, as your app is an SPA... No traditional post request are employed in SPA Apps.

`navgation.NavigateTo("/fetchdata", forceLoad: true);` is wrong. The component FetchData is within the boundary space of your App, and it should be called with forceLoad: false. When you want to go out of the boundary space of your App, say you want to navigate to the url "example.com", you should use forceLoad: true.

When you use `navgation.NavigateTo("/fetchdata", forceLoad: true);`, you actually reload your App anew. And this was and should not be your intention.

How to solve this issue ? Place the button element outside the form element, and it would be a good practice to set the type attribute to `button`, like this:

```
<form class="login-form">
          <input type="text" placeholder="username"/>
          <input type="password" placeholder="password"/>
 </form>

 <button type="button" @onclick=ValidateCredentials>login</button>
```

And

```
public void ValidateCredentials(EventArgs e)
{
     navigation.NavigateTo("/fetchdata");
}
```

Did you notice that the form element is superfluous ?

It's now good time to learn Blazor. Begin at the beginning